# Passing Textbox Multiline to xml

Tags: vba, ms-word

so i have a form with a single textbox.  the user enters in the information and saves at the button.  the text could be single line or multiple as well as could be well over a 1,000 char. i found out that my xml file will auto wrap the the next line if over, to which this causes an error when trying to read the xml file at a later time

here is the code from when the form saves:

```
    IRBNum = ThisDocument.IRBNetID
    XDoc.Load "C:\IRBNet\" & IRBNum & "\Text Files\Project Info.xml"
    Set oNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("Project/Abstract/" & AbstractForm.SecTitle)
    oNode.nodeTypedValue = SubText.Text
```

is there a way to automatically tell my xml file this could be well over 100 chars and could be multiline all in one shot.

Comment: It's difficult to see how a line could be wrapped by looking at the code in your post - there is nothing in XML which I've ever encountered which leads to wrapping when entering a string value of any length.  Maybe you could explain exactly how you're seeing this wrapping?  It might just be an artifact of however you're viewing the content.

Comment: so what is happening is if i have my text line in my xml file as <Text> blah blah blah.etc etc etc. (1000 chars later it will wrap to the next line till the end) blah blah</Text>

when i try to call this at a later time i get: 
Run tine error 5844
One of the values passed to this method or property is incorrect

Comment: Would certainly help to add more of your code so we can try to reproduce - eg show where you declare `XDoc`  Also describe how you determined wrapping was happening - how are you viewing the file content?

Answer (score 0):

so here is the whole private sub of the form:

```
Private Sub Saving_Click()
Dim XDoc, oNode
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    IRBNum = ThisDocument.IRBNetID
    XDoc.Load "C:\IRBNet\" & IRBNum & "\Text Files\Project Info.xml"
    Set oNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("Project/Abstract/" & AbstractForm.SecTitle)
    oNode.nodeTypedValue = SubText.Text
    Set oNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("Project/Abstract/" & AbstractForm.SecTitle & "Pro")
    oNode.nodeTypedValue = True
    XDoc.Save "C:\IRBNet\" & IRBNum & "\Text Files\Project Info.xml"
    AbstractForm.Comp = True
    Call AbstractForm.ReloadForm
    Unload AbstractWrite
    AbstractForm.Show
    
End Sub
```

and then when i recall it, it is going to a selected word document and under the ThisDocument_Open it them pulls that xml part. this is where i am getting the error

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim XDoc, oNode
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    Set oNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("Project/Abstract/Rdesign")
    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Research").Item(1).Range.Text = oNode.nodeTypedValue
End Sub
```

Comment: It's best to post updates by editing your question, and reserve answers for answers.  If you open your XML file in a text editor, do you see any wrapping there?  What type of content control is "Research"?  What is the error you get, and on which line?  Did you omit some code from `Document_Open` ?

Comment: yes the text wraps there, and i have tried to put it all on one line, and it still wraps the text to the next line.  i am using notepad.  i have one value that is 860 chars and it works fine for it, but the follow value is 1500 and gives me an error every time.

Comment: Notepad can't show a line longer than 1024 characters: https://superuser.com/questions/431352/how-to-view-text-files-with-line-length-more-than-1024

Comment: Also  - your content control likely has no problem accepting newline/ carriage return characters if they exist in your XML content.

Comment: I think i figured it out.  the issue is the Control Content text box i am going to.  if it is a rich text box it won't work, plain text box will

Comment: You’ve got that the wrong way round. A Rich Text content control will accept multiple lines including carriage returns by default, a Plain Text content control won’t unless you set the `MultiLine` property.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - in my testing a plain text control would *accept* text with newlines (ie. it doesn't trigger any error), but just not display them.

Comment: @TimWilliams - perhaps *accept* was the wrong word to use

Comment: If the code you have posted is what you are working with there appears to be several lines of code missing from `Document_Open`